# "Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json " error when running pac install latest power shell in my local pc

Tags: powershell, installation, command-line-interface

I have error when running power shell command "pac install latest" on my local pc.
This is what I have done:

1. Installed Power Platform CLI using Windows MSI
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/howto/install-cli-msi
2. running pac install latest, I have the errors:
   [ERROR] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
   [ERROR]   An error occurred while sending the request.
   [ERROR]   The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
   please let me know how to fix these errors.
   Thank you so much

By the way, I can browsing this url without any problem: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: This question is not about source code. It is about using a program. Thus, it is off-topic for SO as described under https://stackoverflow.com/help.